# Beamer sidebar both sides

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to figure out how to make sidebars on both sides of a beamer presentation. I've been reading this: http://gking.harvard.edu/files/beameruserguide2.pdf, particularly around page 60. It mentions something about loading the sidebar outer theme. Is there a way I can load this to give me both sides? Thanks for any help.

Comment: And what information should each sidebar contain, or do you just want a decorative additional sidebar? Which theme are you currently using?

Comment: So far I'm using \usetheme{default} and \useoutertheme{sidebar} in the preamble. On each slide, the names of the different sections appear in order in the left sidebar in a subdued color, except for the current section, which is more emphasized.

Comment: The left sidebar is exactly how I want it. It's the right sidebar that I'm trying to figure out. I want the right sidebar to appear at a particular time, after I've talked about some particular concepts x,y, and z. I want to keep those concepts up there in the right sidebar as a point of comparison for similar concepts that come up later in the talk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is only for some frames, and not all of them, I don't think a "true" sidebar is the best choice. One option is to use `TikZ` to define a "fake" sidebar with the information that you want to display in the selected frames, and then use the `columns` environment to make room for this sidebar in those frames; something along these lines (depending on the theme used and on the actual content to be displayed, you might need to change the colors used and the lengths involved):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\useoutertheme{sidebar} 

\newcommand\MySideInfo{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[structure] 
  ([xshift=-.2\textwidth]current page.north east) 
  rectangle 
  (current page.south east);
\node[yshift=1cm,text width=.18\textwidth,
  anchor=east,font=\color{white}] 
  at (current page.east) 
  {\parbox{\linewidth}{\raggedright\scriptsize Some concept here}};
\node[text width=.18\textwidth,
  anchor=east,font=\color{white}] 
  at (current page.east) 
  {\parbox{\linewidth}{\raggedright\scriptsize Another concept here}};
\node[yshift=-1cm,text width=.18\textwidth,
  anchor=east,font=\color{white}] 
  at (current page.east) 
  {\parbox{\linewidth}{\raggedright\scriptsize Yet another concept here}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section one}
\begin{frame}
\lipsum[4]
\end{frame}

\section{Test section two}
\begin{frame}
\MySideInfo
\begin{columns}
\column{.8\textwidth}
\lipsum[4]
\column{.2\textwidth}
\null
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\MySideInfo
\begin{columns}
\column{.8\textwidth}
\lipsum[4]
\column{.2\textwidth}
\null
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\section{Test section three}
\begin{frame}
\lipsum[4]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]